# Android developing - Making a wireless (Bluetooth/Wi-fi) Keyboard for Computers

Tags: android, keyboard, wireless

I would like to ask what studies are needed for me turn my smartphone into a wireless keyboard and use for desktop/laptop/etc...? How could I achieve this step by step? Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You would require an app which has a keyboard layout (or just use the android softkey) and send the key press code to a computer via Bluetooth.

You computer should have an interface software that can receive you incoming keystroke signal  and convert that into the OS signal.

Actually there is an app in the market which has the same functionality
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse.lite&hl=en